# Access OSX Server over VPN

Tags: networking, macos, vps, osx-server

I have an OSX server in my home and I would like to be able to access some of the services like the Wiki Server over the internet.

However, I because my ISP (xplornet) is not very good, I cannot do things like port forwarding on my router, as they have their own router again on the outside which cannot be disabled (I've tried to do stuff and crashed their network in our area).

I want to be able to access the server externally. I was wondering if I bought a VPS, could I configure a VPN on it and use the IP of the VPS as the IP of my OSX server?

I'm not a network engineer, so I don't even know if that would be possible, nor do I know where to look to even begin.

Comment: Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](http://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Answer (score 0):

you could subscribe to a vps and install os x server and a wiki on it and access *that* over the internet, but if you can't change the settings on your router you'll never be able to host something from your home over the internet.

you could also set up a vpn on that server and vpn into it, although you don't have to vpn to use the wiki.

i don't know of any isp that has their own router outside a client's home but if that's the case the only way is to host from somewhere else, like macminicolo.